# When instantiating a controller with "controller as" syntax via $compile, where exactly does the property get published?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to figure out where exactly the controller object gets published, when using the "controller as" syntax and instantiating the controller with `$compile`. Here's a test I have:

```
describe('"Controller as" syntax', function() {
  it('should work when controller is instantiated via $compile', function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', function($controllerProvider) {
      $controllerProvider.register('DummyController', function() {
        this.message = 'hello there';
      });
    }]);    

    var $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    var view = $compile(
    '<div ng-controller="DummyController as dummy">{{dummy.message}}</div>'
    )($scope);

    $rootScope.$apply();

    // OK - The view is updated
    expect(view.text()).toBe('hello there');

    // FAIL - 'dummy' is not available on the $scope
    expect($scope.dummy.message).toBe('hello there');
  });
});
```

Please see the very last expectation. I expect `dummy` to be available via `$scope`, but it doesn't seem to be there. Am I wrong and it's not supposed to work like this?

I've also discovered that it's available via `$scope.$$childTail` and `$scope.$$childHead`:

```
    // OK - 'dummy' is available here
    expect($scope.$$childTail.dummy.message).toBe('hello there');

    // OK - 'dummy' is available here
    expect($scope.$$childHead.dummy.message).toBe('hello there');
```

Does it mean that there's a child scope created in my case, and `dummy` gets only published on that child scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [$compile docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> #### scope
>
> If set to **true**, then a new scope will be created for this directive.

From [ngController.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngController.js):

```
var ngControllerDirective = [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: '@',
    priority: 500
  };
}];
```

So, it's as expected, my expectation was wrong. The only way to get to that `dummy` property is via those `$$...` things, which are not a part of public API.